# How to combine two rows in a spreadsheet into a single row?

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet

[image]

I want the third row to be a combination of the first two row. The first two rows can be of varying length and will be different length from each other.

How can this be done?

Comment: Are the number of items in each row the same or can row 1 be 3 and row 2 be 4?

Comment: Different, I will edit question

Comment: What version of Excel do you have?

Comment: 16.35 excel for mac

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In **A3** enter:

```
=IF(COLUMNS($A:A)<COUNTA(1:1)+1,INDEX(1:1,COLUMNS($A:A)),INDEX(2:2,COLUMNS($A:A)-COUNTA(1:1)))
```

and copy across.

[image]

This should work for different lengths of data in the first two rows.  It does not require `TEXTJOIN()` or XML filtering.

**EDIT#4:**

The formula is pretty simple-minded.  It just marches across the first row.  Once it has picked up all the contents of the first, it drops down to the second row and starts picking up data starting back at column **A**.

With care, it is possible to extend this to more than two rows.

Comment: I just tested it, and seems to be off?

Comment: @erotsppa  I updated it.......................

Comment: It breaks as soon as you have 4 items in second row (4, 5, 6, 7)

Comment: @erotsppa  You are correct....................I will delete this answer.................

Comment: @erotsppa  Updated answer for arbitrary fills of the first two rows.

Comment: Genius, how does it work?

Comment: @erotsppa  See my **EDIT#4** .........sorry about all the miss-steps.........too much Benadryl and not enough coffee.

Answer (score 1):

If one has the dynamic array formula and TEXTJOIN then put this in A3:

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&TEXTJOIN("</b><b>",TRUE,1:2)&"</b></a>","//b"))
```

[image]

---

If one does not have the dynamic array formula but has TEXTJOIN, put this in A3:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&TEXTJOIN("</b><b>",TRUE,1:2)&"</b></a>","//b"),COLUMN(A1)),"")
```

This may need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting edit mode.  Then Copy over till one gets blanks.

[image]

Comment: Says invalid name error, so I guess not in this version

Comment: @erotsppa then you will want VBA.  You can find TEXTJOIN UDFs many places.  Here is one I created:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39532189/vlookup-with-multiple-criteria-returning-values-in-one-cell